# Android studio 1.5.1 SVN Import

Tags: android, svn, android-studio, version-control

I have updated Android Studio to 1.5.1 , i am trying to checkout project from SVN, but there is no option. I have looked into plugin to install SVN but didn't find anything as well.

[image: Android Studio 1.5.1 version control checkout options]

Is there something i am missing? 
 I reckon earlier android studio versions has SVN checkout option.

Also in the Android Studio preferences i don't see Sub-version option.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use git-svn if you still have to use svn

Comment: could you elaborate on how to use git-svn

Comment: just like a normal git repo then